# Слетает размер img при добавлении дубликатов

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с проблемой, при которой кнопка удаления ведет себя странно. У меня есть корзина с товарами, чистый html и css. На первом скриншоте всё нормально.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при добавлении следующего предмета корзины происходит следующее:

[image: скрин 2 с проблемой]

Снизу прикладываю код:

```css
      .drawerBlock {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 385px;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: -10px 4px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 30px;
  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .cartTotalBlock {
    .priceCount {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    button {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      bottom: 90px;
      width: 95%;
      height: 55px;
      background-color: #9DD558;
      border-radius: 18px;
      border: 0;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    .cartItem {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-content: center;
      margin-top: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      .cartItemImg {
        height: 110px;
        width: 110px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: 0 -7px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-top: 4px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-right: 8px;
      }
      b {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      img:first-child {
        padding-right: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .removeBtn {
        opacity: 0.6;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
        &:hover {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div className="cartItem">
  <img src="images/book3.png" alt="Book" />
  <div className="descriptionBlock">
    <p>Карточка активации учебной программы "Правила дорожного движения"</p>
    <b>120 rub</b>
  </div>
  <img className="removeBtn" src="/images/btn-remove.svg" />
</div>

<div className="cartItem">
  <img src="images/book3.png" alt="Book" />
  <div className="descriptionBlock">
    <p>Карточка активации учебной программы "Правила дорожного движения"</p>
    <b>120 rub</b>
  </div>
  <img className="removeBtn" src="/images/btn-remove.svg" />
</div>
<div className="cartItem">
  <img src="images/book3.png" alt="Book" />
  <div className="descriptionBlock">
    <p>Карточка активации учебной программы "Правила дорожного движения"</p>
    <b>120 rub</b>
  </div>
  <img className="removeBtn" src="/images/btn-remove.svg" />
</div>
<div className="cartItem">
  <img src="images/book3.png" alt="Book" />
  <div className="descriptionBlock">
    <p>Карточка активации учебной программы "Правила дорожного движения"</p>
    <b>120 rub</b>
  </div>
  <img className="removeBtn" src="/images/btn-remove.svg" />
</div>

<div className="cartTotalBlock">
  <table className="priceCount" cellPadding={4}>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <th>256 rub</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tax %:</td>
        <th>16 rub</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button>Checkout</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас ошибки в scss

Comment: А можете указать на ошибку?

Comment: Я точно не скажу, онлайн компиляторы ругаются на не закрытую(ые) "}"

Comment: 3 не закрытые фигурные скобки.